# How does hadoop handle changes to rows ingested from an RDBMS

Tags: mysql, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, sqoop

I have a scenario where data is ingested into hadoop from a MYSQL database everyday into a dated folder. Few rows will be edited everyday and there might also be some schema changes. How do we handle this in hadoop if I am only interested in the latest data and schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports) is the documentation for incremental imports in Sqoop. Also, Sqoop can takes the table name while importing the data, so if the schema changes the Sqoop command should be the same.

> bin/sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/bigdata --table widgets -m 1

Comment: while that is good for the new data, how do we handle it when someone has edited a record in MySql?

Comment: Sqoop supports both append and lastmodified.

Comment: Sqoop only supports the "lastmodified" option when there is a field with a timestamp in the table you are trying to ingest. Is this realy the answer to OP's question?